# Rspec не работает с have_title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Прохожу Ruby on Rails tutorial. Возникла такая проблема с Capybara 2.14 и rspec-rails 3.6.

Данный тест проваливается:

```
it "should have the title 'Help'" do
  visit '/static_pages/help'
  expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
end
```

Код ошибки:

```
StaticPages Get help page should have the title 'Help'
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
   expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

А этот успешно проходит тест:

```
it "should have the title 'Help'" do
  visit '/static_pages/help'
  expect(page).to have_selector('title', text:"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
end
```

Вот собственно help.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Help')%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title)%></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Ruby on Rails Tutorial SampleApp</h1>
    <p>
      Find me in
      You can get help on
      <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/#help"> Ruby on rails tutorial</a>
      app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить `|` на `\|` в `have_title`

Comment: Не знаю почему, но это помогло. Если можете объясните. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка, которую вы передаете в `have_title` автоматически конвертируется в **Regexp**. А в регулярном выражении символ `|` имеет специальное значение - **или**. Добавив `\` вы тем самым экранируете символ и он означает сам себя, а не специальное значение.

Comment: Все ясно. Спасибо. Как я понимаю в версии capybara 2.1.0 поиск был реализован по другому( не через регулярные выражения), так как в примерах в книге все работает хорошо.

Comment: судя по исходному коду, там ничего не поменялось http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/2.10.1/Capybara%2FQueries%2FTitleQuery:initialize